# Can I put the upstream directive inside server context?

Tags: nginx

The `[upstream][1]` directive in [ngx_http_upstream_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) is supposed to be in the `http` context.

However, I'll have more than one `server` inside the `http` context, and I would like to have multiple `upstream` with the same name but different `server`s inside.

Could I put the `upstream` directive inside the `server` context to not conflict with the names? In other words, can we have lexical scope in the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

If you try, you'll get:

```
nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in ...
```

You'll have to give it another name.